# make multiple objects automatically move for how many objects have been specified in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a tiled game that has NPC's in it. I can create one NPC successfully but when I draw more than one they share the same position after a few seconds of the code running. I created this sample to demonstrate what I mean.

```
import pygame, random, math

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600)) 

NPCP = {'Bob' : (2,6), 'John' : (4,4)} # 25, 19 max width and height
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, (100))
sMove = True

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            sMove = True
    screen.fill((0,0,255))
    for name in NPCP:
        x,y = NPCP.get(name)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (x*32,y*32,50,50))
        if sMove == True:
            move = random.randint(1,4)
            sMove = False
        if move == 1:
            if math.floor(y) > 2:
                y -= 2
        if move == 2:
            if math.floor(y) < 17:
                y += 2
        if move == 3:
            if math.floor(x) < 23:
                x += 2
        if move == 4:
            if math.floor(x) > 2:
                x -= 2
        print(x,y)
        NPCP[name] = (x,y)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

I use a dictionary to create these NPC's or rectangles in this case. I move them around with a timer and a random number ranging from 1 to 4 to select which movement to do. I use a for loop to run for each NPC. I would like to know how to allow these rectangles to not move around the same way and for the position not to eventually change to the same position and move differently from each other. I also want to have it that it uses the dictionary to do so.

Comment: They get the same position, because the movement is clamped to the borders of the screen.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I dont think that is happening as`  if math.floor(x) < 23: ` only is checking if the rectangles dont go off the screen. that code itself doesnt change x or y at all but what it runs does to move the object around

Comment: Of course it does. If the border of the screen is reached the movement is not performed, but the other object still moves!

Comment: Skip `sMove = False` and the objects will move individually.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I was using sMove with the timer to time the moment so it doesn't spreed around the screen. But if it courses that issue is there another way to slow the rectangles down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move then objects individually, then you've to generate a random direction for each object.

In your code only on direction is generated for all objects, because `sMove` is set `False` immediately after the direction for the first object was generated. This direction is used for all the objects.
Further the move direction (`move`) is never reset to 0. This causes that the last random direction is applied in all following frames, till the direction is changed again.

> ```
> if sMove == True:
>     move = random.randint(1,4)
>     sMove = False
> ```

Reset `sMove` reset `move` after the loop and, to solve the issue:

```py
for name in NPCP:
    x,y = NPCP.get(name)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (x*32,y*32,50,50))
    if sMove == True:
        move = random.randint(1,4)
    if move == 1:
        if math.floor(y) > 2:
            y -= 2
    if move == 2:
        if math.floor(y) < 16:
            y += 2
    if move == 3:
        if math.floor(x) < 22:
            x += 2
    if move == 4:
        if math.floor(x) > 2:
            x -= 2
    print(x,y)
    NPCP[name] = (x,y)

sMove = False # wait for next timer
move = 0      # stop moving
```

[image]